# Ionic Storage is it possible to use SQL anymore?

Tags: mysql, json, sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic2

The newest Ionic now uses "Storage" which relies on a key value pair based storage. Now I'm a webdeveloper and I use MySQL almsot everyday, and I'd love to use it in Ionic too. Now there are numerous SQLite and WebSQL tutorials available but I read everywhere that in the future this will drop so be prepared to use key pair value databases.

Now I'm confused, because how can you do cross related queries in databases for relational data? I always presumed relational databases are way more efficient and keeps the data organized. Is this even possible with key value?

I thought about using JSON, but that would mean every time you want to add or delete a row, you need to rewrite the whole JSON database... And how would you update one row with the Storage functionality of Ionic?

Comment: I don't know where you're under the impression that using JSON requires a complete database rewrite. It probably only needs to manipulate one row/document worth of data. If you're heavily invested in JSON, check out [Postgres](http://postgresql.org) and the [deep support for JSON data querying and manipulation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-json.html) if not [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org). Other options worth considering.

Comment: Relational databases are going to go the way of the dinosaur - by which I mean they'll last for a hundred million years, maybe two, and will only be wiped out when 30 trillion tons of space trash come thundering down and leave a divot the size of Ohio somewhere.

Comment: as @BobJarvis said, Relational DB is here to stay. It is just the fact that for the bulk of new software we make these days, such as mobile Apps and HTML5 apps, the key-value storages seem to be enough and yet easy on resources.

Comment: But how would I use that with sort of relational database? Can I use the key as the table identifier and use JSON for the value? And to update the key you must add another row to the current JSON string and put that back in the table?

Comment: The 'key' is meant to be what you find values with. So you should not be updating the 'key'. I could be more specific if you can make the question less broad. for example what sort of data you are trying to store in SQLite?

Comment: Yeah I meant update the value of the key table with the new JSON string. Basically it comes down to values of lets say books, names, writers, with their birth of date, etc. Just a very simple relational database with standard values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are options other than WebSQL for a relational database in web apps. [SQL.js](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/) is SQLite cross-compiled to Javascript and [lovefield](https://github.com/google/lovefield) is a relational database built on top of indexeddb. The fact that it's possible to build a relational database on top of indexeddb was one of the arguments for dropping WebSQL. Neither of these options are as performant as WebSQL, so there are proposals such as [rdb](https://arthurhsu.github.io/rdb/) for adding a relational database API to the web.

Since you are building a hybrid Ionic app, you have access to native functionality as well. There is a [plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/) that gives you a similar API to WebSQL and will work even if browsers drop WebSQL. If you need a relational database in your app, I think this is your best option.